# How to create a timer Counter in C#

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to create a timer that checks how long the computer is locked The idea is for the timer to count 30 minutes and after it gets to 30 minutes execute some code. so far i try this

```
int startin = 1800 - DateTime.Now.Second;
var time = new System.Threading.Timer(o => Console.WriteLine("hello"), null, startin * 1000, 1800000);
```

which works except that I need to stop and reset the timer when the user logs on.
Any idea? thanks

Comment: So, your question has nothing to do with timers in general, but you are actually looking for a way to capture the event of a user logging on?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper And then silently stop copying delicate files over ftp :-)

Comment: I have the event capture working i just need to count down 30 minutes from the time the user lock the computer, and if they log on then stop and reset the timer until they lock the computer again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Timer
{
    CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public Task Wait(TimeSpan delay)
    {
        return Task.Delay(delay, _cts.Token);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var t = new Timer();
await t.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
```